# How to check if input is string or byte in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-6.0

I made a very simple program where user needs to write his name and age. Then a message box pops up and shows the name and age. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOdF5.jpg )

```
public partial class MySecondApplication : Form
{
    public MySecondApplication()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAge.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void txtAge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdSubmit.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var name = txtName.Text;
        var age = Convert.ToByte(txtAge.Text);
        MessageBox.Show($"Your name is {name} and You're {age} years old.");
    }

    private void cmdExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

How can I do this: if age is a string, a message box pops up and says "the age is not a number and the user needs to try again"?

Comment: Read up on [`int.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There's a MaskedTextBox that can reject invalid input. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is nothing wrong with convert and this will work if all data is valid.

```
    private void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var name = txtName.Text;
      var age = Convert.ToByte(txtAge.Text);
      MessageBox.Show($"Your name is {name} and You're {age} years old.");
    }
```

There are several ways to validate your data and here is another approach you might want to use.

```
    private void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string name = txtName.Text;
      short age; //This is an Int16 with a range of -32,768 to +32,767
      short.TryParse(txtAge.Text,out age);
      string ageStatement = age == 0 ? "your age is unknown" : 
                                      $"you're {age} years old";
      MessageBox.Show($"Your name is {name} and {ageStatement}.");
```

The TryParse

```
    short.TryParse(txtAge.Text,out age);
```

If the string data in txtAge.Text is not a number the TryParse will set the age (out parameter) to 0 (zero)

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = txtName.Text;
Byte outAge;
bool result= Byte.TryParse(txtAge.Text, NumberStyles.Integer,null as IFormatProvider, out outAge);

if (!result)
{
//show your message box;
}
else
{
var age=outAge;
}
```

Please check below link for brief description

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkktxbeh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var name = txtName.Text;
    int age;
    if(Int32.TryParse("txtAge.Text, out age))
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Your name is {name} and You're {age} years old.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid age");         
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try use `NumericUpDown` control with Minimum and Maximum value set to some reasonable values and don't reimplement validation and parsing